# Gluing line bundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Say that I have a scheme $X$ with an open cover $\{U_i\}$ and I know $\operatorname{Pic}(U_i)$ for all $i$. Is this enough information to say something meaningful about $\operatorname{Pic}(X)$? Certainly any line bundle on $X$ will restrict to line bundles on the $U_i$, so we should get an injection $\operatorname{Pic}(X)\rightarrow \oplus \operatorname{Pic}(U_i)$. But I don't think this is enough information to decide if this map is also surjective, we'd need some information about the overlaps, right? What if instead of an open cover $\{U_i\}$, we knew all the Picard groups for a basis $\{U_i\}$, does that change anything?

Comment: In general, the map $\operatorname{Pic}(X)\rightarrow\prod\operatorname{Pic}(U_i)$ will be neither injective nor surjective (and by the way, this is a product since the restriction may be non trivial on infinitely many $U_i$). In the case of $\mathbb{P}^1=\mathbb{A}^1\cup\mathbb{A}^1$, you see that the map is not into. In the case of $\mathbb{P}^1=\mathbb{P}^1\cup\mathbb{P}^1$ it is not onto. But for a less trivial example, take $E=(E\setminus\{a\})\cup(E\setminus\{b\})$ where $E$ is an elliptic curve.

Comment: In fact $\operatorname{Pic}$ can be expressed as the $H^1$ of some sheaf ($\mathcal{O}_X^*$). Thus $\operatorname{Pic}$ won't be a sheaf, but there are some homological tools (for instance Mayer Vietoris long exact sequences if $X$ is cover by two open sets, spectral sequence in general) which can be helpful (though for $\operatorname{Pic}$ they usually aren't...)